# How to check if the elements in array A exist in array B and return the index of B

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I spent time searching on this question but couldn't find any existing solution. Suppose I have array A and array B

```
A = np.array([2,3,3,3,4,5])
B = np.array([3,4])
```

if I use `np.isin`: it will return `array([False,  True,  True, False])`. However, what I really want is some function that can return

```
array([-1,  0, 0, 0, 1, -1])
```

where the first and last -1 represents the elements in A can't be found in B, and 0 represents the element is found in the index 0 in B, and 1 is the index 1 in B.

Any elegant solution?

Comment: What if a value occurs multiple times?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Updated